# Copy Cells From One Tab to Another Based on Matching Column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is what I need the sheet to do.

Assign tab (Source)
When the button is clicked on the assign spreadsheet it should match the contents of cell A2 with column A on the destination tab and copy cells B2:E2 into the appropriate the column

[published sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRdzT0oASEX9c-p1PsTaNGZU5HvFf9IvyqrgKpnFmfOpQ-9Q4tY8xQFjO9lkB3cXSsQ4s7AC5RyENn9/pubhtml?gid=1224712314&single=true)

Sheet 1 tab (Destination)
Destination B2 to Col F, C2 to Col G, D2 to Col H and E2 to Col J

[published sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRdzT0oASEX9c-p1PsTaNGZU5HvFf9IvyqrgKpnFmfOpQ-9Q4tY8xQFjO9lkB3cXSsQ4s7AC5RyENn9/pubhtml?gid=1281122410&single=true)

Answer (score 1):

#### Probably not what you want

But the best I could figure from what little explanation is provided

```
function copyMatched() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//source sheet
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//dest sheet
  const n = ssh.getRange("A2").getValue();
  const vs = ssh.getRange(3, 1, ssh.getLastRow() - 2, 5).getValues();
  let oA = ssh.getRange(3, 1, ssh.getLastRow() - 2, 5).getValues().map(r => {
    if (r[0] == n) {
      return [r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4]];
    }
  }).filter(e => e);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(oA));
  if(oA.length) {
    dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, oA.length, oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("No matches found");
  }
}
```

My Data:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |

Output:

| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: I tried it but I got this error Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
copyMatched @ Code.gs:5

Comment: Perhaps you need to change the sheet names

Comment: I did that. It wont let me copy the code here. Now it gives me this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
copyMatched @ Code.gs:13. Sheet1 has over 10K of rows in it.

Comment: Again that seems  to me that the destination sheet name my be incorrect.

Comment: Destination is Sheet1 and source is Assign. They are correct.

Comment: Try it again....

Comment: Here is a link to a screen recording and the running of the script. https://watch.screencastify.com/v/XdUS1yfYAGE2hWJm9Xrn

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow links from this site

Comment: Here I uploaded it to youtube. You cannot add pictures in comments and this is the only way I can show you that the sheet names are correct and it does not work. Maybe if you see it you can tell me why. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPNN5zmoe9Y

Comment: I'm not doubting that you changed the names.  I made a change please run it and let me know the outcome.

Comment: BTW you can upload animated gifs to this site

Comment: It said no matches found but it does match because the script I will post next if it lets me does return the name to the correct place.